# Improper Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I am supposed to solve the following question:

For what function classes it makes sense to talk about the Improper Riemann Integral?

I know that we can talk now about bounded functions defined on unbounded interval or unbounded functions defined on bounded interval.

But is there any more specific answer?

Comment: Bounded is not enough. The function $f(x)=1$ is bounded, but the improper Riemann integral over the entire number line doesn't exist. Also, continuity must be discussed.

Comment: @Arthur so when we include continuity and differentiability, will it be correct?

Comment: As I said, $f(x)=1$ is continuous, differentiable and bounded, but the improper integral doesn't exist. On the other hand, there are discontinuous functions with existing improper integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, you can assume that the interval is in the form $[a,+\infty)$ for some $a$ (the $(-\infty,a]$ case us similar). Then the integral of $f$ on $[a,+\infty)$ is defined as
$$\int_a^{+\infty} f := \lim_{b \to +\infty } \int_a^b f$$
And if $f$ is "unbounded at $a$", then the integral on $(a,b]$ is defined as
$$\int_a^b f = \lim_{x \to a+0} \int_x^b f$$
What do we need for these definitions to "make sense"?

Comment: We need to have continous functions? just that?

Comment: @PeterF. No, we don't need continuity. For the first case, we need that $\forall b >a$, $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, because we could not take the limit otherwise. And we also need the limit to be finite. What do you think about the $(a,b]$ case?

Comment: We do not need limit to be finite, but still we need integrability on interval  (a,b] ?

Comment: @PeterF. The finiteness of the limit is correct, but how do you define the integrability on $(a,b]$?

Comment: It has to be countinous from the right side?

Comment: @PeterF. No. You should think of a property like in the first case - that allows you to talk about the given limit at the first place.

Comment: Can you please write me? I am completely lost

Comment: @PeterF. In the case of $[a, +\infty)$, we wanted integrability on $[a,b]$ for all $b>a$. In the case of $(a,b]$, we need something similar: Integrability on $[c,b]$ for all $c\in (a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you so much